# Accessing the Python interactive help system from Python code

Tags: python-3.x

I have a program that uses the `code` module to present an emulation of the Python REPL. However, one major flaw in `code`'s implementation is that it doesn't give the user access to `help()`, which would be very very handy for my purpose.

How can I find `help()` and stuff it into my interactive interpreter emulator's locals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `help` function object can be accessed as `builtins.help`; the `site` module assigns sticks it in `__builtins__` on startup if it detects that Python is running in interactive mode.